# Error when installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client' package onto Xamarin project

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to install the  'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client' nuget package onto a Xamarin android project. This is going to be used to connect to a database and use an API to manipulate the data. This is the package I am trying to install

[image]

This is the error I am receiving. I am aware you can change it so your app targets a new version of android, but this doesn't say what version it needs to run on. Has anyone got a solution? Or any alternatives to connecting to a database without using SQLite 
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: this package hasn't been updated in over 2 years, it doesn't appear to support any Xamarin compatible profiles

Comment: Are you trying to get WebAPI to run **in the mobile app**? I don't think this should be installed in a mobile app project.

Comment: A workaround is download the NuGet package using [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/),  rename it to be `.zip`, then extract the files and reference the assembly directly.